# OCaml Explicit polymorphic type annotations

Tags: recursion, polymorphism, ocaml, recursive-datastructures, polymorphic-functions

I would enjoy to receive some helpful comments concerning an example given on: 
http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual021.html#toc79

> 7.12  Explicit polymorphic type annotations

```
type 'a t = Leaf of 'a | Node of ('a * 'a) t

let rec depth : 'a. 'a t -> 'b = function
|Leaf _ -> 1
| Node x -> 1 + depth x
```

I understand this example function, but when I try to define a 'map-like' function of type

```
'a. 'a t -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b t
```

e.g.:

```
let rec tmap: 'a. 'a t ->(f:'a->'b) -> 'b t = function
|Leaf x ->  Leaf( f x) 
|Node x -> let res = tmap x in Node(res);;
```

I get the following error:

```
Characters 67-77:
  |Leaf x ->  Leaf( f x)
              ^^^^^^^^^^

Error: This expression has type 'c t but an expression was expected of type
         (f:'a -> 'b) -> 'b t
```

which I do not completely understand.
I would appreciate any helpful comment.

Comment: You wanted to write let rec tmap : 'a. 'a t -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b t = fun f -> function ... ?

Answer (score 4):

You have a few problems, like improperly placed parenthesis around `f`, forgotten argument to the `tmap` function in the `Node` branch, and you've forget the quantifier for `'b`. So, finally, with the help of PatJ we can write the following:

```
type 'a t = Leaf of 'a | Node of ('a * 'a) t

let rec depth : 'a. 'a t -> 'b = function
  | Leaf _ -> 1
  | Node x -> 1 + depth x


let rec tmap: 'a 'b. 'a t -> f:('a -> 'b) -> 'b t =
  fun t ~f -> match t with
    | Leaf x -> Leaf (f x)
    | Node x ->
      Node (tmap ~f:(fun (x,y) -> f x, f y) x)

tmap (Node (Leaf (7,8))) ~f:(fun x -> x + 1, x + 2);;
- : (int * int) t = Node (Leaf ((8, 9), (9, 10)))
```

Comment: In depth, 'b is not polymorphic. Also, you can remove that mention of -rectypes now :-)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to get the second argument.

```
let rec tmap:
 'a. 'a t ->(f:'a->'b) -> 'b t = (* asking for two arguments *)
 function (* takes only the first argument *)
|Leaf x -> Leaf( f x)
|Node x -> let res = tmap x in Node(res);;
```

Also, `'b` must be polymorphic too, as you want to generate nested tuples as long as you descend through the tree.

This should be, thanks to ivg:

```
let rec tmap : 'a 'b. 'a t -> f:('a->'b) -> 'b t =  fun t ~f ->
  match t with
  |Leaf x -> Leaf( f x)
  |Node x -> let f (a,b) = (f a, f b) in Node ( tmap x ~f ) ;;
```

Comment: this is just an incorrect syntax for type annotation, parens in the wrong place =)

Comment: Fixed. I seriously need sleep -_-,

Comment: me too, I've missed the `'b`

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your great help. 
Now my test cases work out as intended:

let int_tree = Node(Node(Leaf((3,-1),(0,4))));; 
let char_tree = Node(Node(Leaf(('a','c'),('d','c'))));;

tmap int_tree ~f:(fun x -> x*x);; 
- : int t = Node (Node (Leaf ((9, 1), (0, 16))))

tmap char_tree ~f:(fun x -> Char.uppercase x);; 
- : char t = Node (Node (Leaf (('A', 'C'), ('D', 'C'))))